# Zapier Reformatting a Get Fetch Response

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, zapier

I am having some issues with Zapier and fetching some information.

What I am trying to do is fetch a url, receive a json response and send the entire response back to the next step to do additional processing.

Zapier seems to be ignoring the callback or any other code I wrote and just sending a 'zapier formatted' response to the next step, but NOT in json format. Below are code samples:

Request to client

```
var authHeaders = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxx',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: authHeaders
};

fetch('www.url.com', options)
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function (json) {
    callback(null, json)
  })
  .catch(callback);
```

Zapier next step option in the dropdown:

```
input.name === harry,bob,sally
input.color === red, blue, green
```

Response from client

```
{
  cats: [
    {name: 'harry', color: 'red'},
    {name: 'bob', color: 'blue'},
    {name: 'sally', color: 'green'},
    {name: 'mary', color: 'green'},
    {name: 'george', color: 'green'}
  ]
}
```

What I want in the next zapier step is the clients response and not the Zapier Interpretation so I can do normal looping and parsing of a json object.

```
cats.filter(function(cat){
  return cat.color === 'green'
})
```

**I want all the cats that are green to be returned to the next step. How can I do this, if all the cat attributes are in different zapier fields?**

Another thing I tried is to reformat the zapier next step response after I make the `GET` request but zapier doesn't listen to me.

```
fetch('www.url.com', options)
  .then(function(res) {
    callback(null, {dog: 'yorkie'})
  })
  .catch(callback);
```

The above code should just send the object I am passing on, `{dog: 'yorkie'}` but it returns the same 'zapier formatted cat response'.

Furthermore, when I didn't follow the zapier callback format and just put in the `fetch` request, it too sent back the 'zapier formatted cat response' to the next step.

```
fetch('www.url.com', options)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely want to do all your filtering in the JS step and only emit the records you care about instead of emitting all the records and making new steps that filter them.

```
fetch('www.url.com', options)
    .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(function (json) {
        json = json.filter(record => record.color === 'green');
        callback(null, json);
    })
    .catch(callback);
```

If we get objects with nested lists - it can be difficult to get them back into the raw JS object format in follow up steps - so your best bet is to return an object with no nested arrays.